# varios filtros en php

Tags: php

hola necesito poner varios filtros en una pagina como una búsqueda de varios campos
 tengo una tabla donde arroja toda la informacion y mis filtros son fecha de inicio ,fecha final y departamento este es mi codigo,pero mi consulta para realizar la busqueda de las fechas y el departamento no se como realizarlas

```html
 <center><h1>Solicitud Pendiente</h1><br></center>
<form method="post" id="fomr1">


    <center>
<td><font color="#000">Fecha Inicial:</font><input type="date" name="fechaini" id="fechafin"></td>
<td><font color="#000">Fecha Final:</font><input type="date" name="fechafin" id="fechafin" ></td>

        <label  for="select">Departamento:</label><select name="id_departamento" id="select" required placeholder="" style="width:330px; height: 25px">
                                  <option value="">Seleccionar..</option>
                                  <?php
                                  
                                  $departamento = "select id_departamento, nombre ,id_gerencia from departamento  where status=1";
                                  $mostrardepartamento=mysql_query($departamento);
                                  while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrardepartamento)){
                                  ?>
                                  
                                  <option value="<?php echo $i["id_departamento"];?>"><?php 
                                      $i["id_gerencia"];?><?php
                                      echo $i["nombre"];?></option>
                                  
                                  <?php
                                  }
                                  ?>
                                  <?php
                                  
                                  $empleadou = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$username' ");
                                  $nosepon= mysql_fetch_array($empleadou);
                                  
                                  ?>
                    </select>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Mostrar" name="mostrar" id="mostrar" ></td>
 </center>
</form>
  
    <br>
  <div class="tbl-header">
   <center> <table class="bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="tab">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID folio</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width:30px;">Fecha</th>
  <th scope="col">Departamento</th>
        <th scope="col">Descripción del trabajo</th>
        <th scope="col">Nombre servicio</th>
        <th scope="col">Costo</th>
        <th scope="col">Autorización Solicitante</th>
  <th scope="col">Autorización Dirección</th>
  <th scope="col">Autorización Gerencia</th>
        <th scope="col">Revisa trabajo</th>
  <th scope="col">Recibe trabajo Terminado</th>
        <th scope="col">Nombre empleado</th>
        <th scope="col">Tipo de solicitud</th>
            
 </tr>
       <?php
       

                  $empleadou = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$usernamee' ");
                  $nosepon= mysql_fetch_array($empleadou);

           
          
             if(($_POST['fechaini']=="") && ($_POST['fechafin']==""))
   {
   $consulta="";
   }else
      { 
     $consulta="AND s.fecha  BETWEEN '".$_POST['fechaini']."' AND '".$_POST['fechafin']."'   ";
             }
             if ($_POST["id_departamento"]=="")
                 {
                     $consulta="";
                 }else
                 {
                     $consulta="AND s.id_departamento  BETWEEN '".$_POST['id_departamento']."";
    }

$so = "SELECT s.Id_folio, s.fecha,s.descripcion_trabajo, s.Id_servicio,s.tipo_solicitud, s.costo, s.id_vehiculo,s.id_departamento, d.id_departamento,d.nombre,u.Empleado_Nombre, u.Empleado_id, t.Id_servicio, t.Nombre_servicio,s.Autoriza_Soli,s.Autoriza_Ger,s.Autoriza_GerIs ,s.Autoriza_trab,s.Autoriza_termi  FROM solicitud as s, departamento as d, usuarios as u, tipo_servicio as t WHERE  s.Empleado_id =u.Empleado_id and s.id_departamento=d.id_departamento and s.Id_servicio =t.Id_servicio and Autoriza_termi=0 and Autoriza_trab=0 AND horaAutorizaG IS NULL AND estatus = '1' ".$consulta."";
          
      $mostrarso=mysql_query($so);
      while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrarso)){
           ?>
          
      <tr>

        <td><a href=<?php echo "Sform2.php?Id_folio=".$i['Id_folio']." "?>><?php echo $i["Id_folio"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i["fecha"];?></td>

        <td ><?php echo $i["nombre"];?></td>
        <td><textarea name="" cols="10" rows="2" autofocus class="form-textarea" id="input_7" title="" data-component="textarea"  textarea readonly="readonly"><?php echo $i["descripcion_trabajo"];?></textarea></td>        
       
        <td ><?php echo $i["Nombre_servicio"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i["costo"];?></td>
        
          <?php if($i[13]==1){$marcar="checked";}else{$marcar="";}?>
  <td ><input type="checkbox" disabled <?php echo $marcar;?>></td>
 <?php if($i[15]==3){$marcar1="checked";}else{$marcar1="";}?>
  <td><input type="checkbox" disabled <?php echo $marcar1;?>></td>
 <?php if($i[14]==2){$marcar2="checked";}else{$marcar2="";}?>
  <td><input type="checkbox" disabled <?php echo $marcar2;?>></td>
 
        <?php if($i[16]==4){$marcar3="checked";}else{$marcar3="";}?>
  <td><input type="checkbox" disabled <?php echo $marcar3;?>></td>
 <?php if($i[17]==5){$marcar4="checked";}else{$marcar4="";}?>
  <td><input type="checkbox" disabled <?php echo $marcar4;?>></td>
    
        <td><?php echo $i["Empleado_Nombre"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i["tipo_solicitud"];?></td>
          
          

      </tr>
      <?php
 }
    echo"<a hre>"
 ?>
      </thead>
    </table></center>
  </div>
```

Comment: ok chica bienvenida al foro, por un lado te comento que estas usando un librería deprecada como lo es mysql, deberías de estar usando mysqli o pdo para estar actualizada con las nuevas versiones de php, por otro lado falta información sobre el proceso, por ejemplo el código donde llega la petición o formulario, otra cosa es que es mala práctica realizar las querys donde se van a usar por asu decirlo, como por ejemplo dentro del select html, el mantenimiento va a ser un problema a futuro, coloca el codi8go donde llega la peticion y lo que quieres hacer al final y partimos de allí. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que solo   quieras construir el where de tu select podrias empezar inicialmente con las condiciones fijas que no requieran de lo que llegue en el $_POST

enseguida solo se le añade a la condición los campos que traigan algún valor

```
$consulta=" WHERE  s.Empleado_id =u.Empleado_id and s.id_departamento=d.id_departamento and s.Id_servicio =t.Id_servicio and Autoriza_termi=0 and Autoriza_trab=0 AND horaAutorizaG IS NULL AND estatus = '1' ";

if(isset($_POST['fechaini'])&&$_POST['fechaini'])
   $consulta.=" AND s.fecha>=CONVERT('".$_POST['fechaini']."',DATE)";
if(isset($_POST['fechafin'])&&$_POST['fechafin'])
   $consulta.=" AND s.fecha<=CONVERT('".$_POST['fechafin']."',DATE)";
if (isset($_POST["id_departamento"])&&$_POST["id_departamento"]>0)
   $consulta.=" AND s.id_departamento=".$_POST['id_departamento'];
```

para finalmente agregarlos a tu sentencia $so.

Comment: muchisimas gracias si me sirvio ahora añadire otro filtro @Juan Carlos

Comment: y para anexar otro filtro pero que este sea independiente de los otros tres al hacer la consulta tiene que ser aparte?